# condition number inequal.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

i was asking myself if there is some connection between condition numbers for more than just two matrices: $\kappa(Z^{-1}X) \leq \kappa(Z^{-1}Y)\kappa(Y^{-1}X)$ for matrices $X,Y,Z$ being sym.pos.def. I guess if this statement is true at all, one could see that by working with Reighley-quotients as usually in those cases. Is there some nice way to see whether the statement is true or not? Many thanks!

Comment: Just look at the definition of the condition number and use the sub-multiplicativity of the operator norm.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, i forgot about where the condition number came from and wanted to do it via eigenvalue theorems. Thanks a lot and have a nice day!